# Looking to do a one-side buffer with QGIS v2.18.9

Tags: qgis, buffer, qgis-processing

I'm working on a project that requires a 30m buffer around a linear feature. The feature represents the coast and I need the buffer to show 30m inland from the line representing the coast. Is there a way to do this using QGIS?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the **Single sided buffers (and offset lines) for lines** tool from the *Processing Toolbox*:

```
GDAL/OGR > [OGR] Geoprocessing > Single sided buffers (and offset lines) for lines
```

[image: GUI]

---

Example:

[image: Example]